# Disable OSP System Beep (PC Speaker)

Tags: okuma

The control screen beeps when I type or touch anything. Every key stroke.

How can I disable this? Is there a way to do this by command line interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet most Okuma users don't even hear the beep, seeing as how noisy a lot of factory floors are.
In a lab environment though, it can be quite annoying.

Thankfully, turning it off is easy.

1. Open the start menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + ⎚ **OR** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>)
2. Type "CMD" + ⎆ To open the Command Prompt
3. Type "sc stop halbeep" to disable the beep
4. Type "sc config halbeep start= disabled" to stop the service from starting again

[image: Disable beet using command prompt]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to temporarily disable the beep with net command.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net stop halbeep

The HalBeep service was stopped successfully.
```